# vba saving word file to created folder

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written the code below, currently it creates a folder. However I would like to save the same word doc to that folder. Any pointers on where I am going wrong??

Thanks

```
Sub newfold()
    Dim strNewFolderName As String
    strNewFolderName = "New Folder " & (Month(Now())) & " " & Year(Now)
    If Len(Dir("c:\Users\Jabaar\Documents\" & strNewFolderName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir ("c:\Users\Jabaar\Documents\" & strNewFolderName)
    End If 
    Dim PathName As String
    PathName = ("New Folder " & MonthName(Month(Now())) & " " & Year(Now))
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs "c:\Users\Jabaar\Documents\" & "(strNewFolderName)" + ".doc"
End Sub
```

Comment: The file is currently saving with in my documents folder under the name of New Folder 2 2014. I see the issue now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs "c:\Users\Jabaar\Documents\" & "(strNewFolderName)" + ".doc"
```

with

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="c:\Users\Jabaar\Documents\" & strNewFolderName & "\" & Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0) & ".doc", _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
```

where `Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0)` takes current name of file without extension. You could replace it with desired name:

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="c:\Users\Jabaar\Documents\" & strNewFolderName & "\" & "newFile.doc", _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
```

Comment: You seem to have hit the nail on the head. I been playing around coming out with this. 'ActiveDocument.SaveAs "c:\Users\Jabaar\Documents\" & strNewFolderName & "\" & "test" + ".doc'

Answer (score 0):

This is what have done and it seems work.

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs "c:\Users\Jabaar\Documents\" & strNewFolderName & "\" & "test" + ".doc
```

The solution @simoco provided is what I was looking for, so thanks for confirming the formatting of it @simoco